# DFS Adjacency matrix

Tags: c, depth-first-search

I'm trying to make a directed DFS traversal path from an adjacency matrix. Basically print out the path in nodes, but the output is always bad for some reason. Even though the code looks sound, it never actually follows the path.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

void DFS(int i, int graph[][MAX], int n, int visited[MAX] );
void visit_all(int graph[][MAX], int n);
void read_matrix(int graph [][MAX], int n);



int main() {

  int graph[MAX][MAX];
  int n;

  printf("Input matrix dimension: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);


  if (n>MAX) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Too large\n");
    exit(1);
  }


  read_matrix(graph, n);
  visit_all(graph, n);
  return 0;

}


void DFS(int v, int graph[][MAX], int n, int visited[MAX]) {

   int w;

   printf("%d ", v);
   visited[v] = 1;


   for(w=0;w<n;w++)
     if (visited[w] == 0 && graph[v][w] == 1)
       DFS(w, graph, n, visited); 
}       

void visit_all(int graph[][MAX], int n) {

   int v, visited[MAX];

   for(v=0;v<n;v++)
     visited[v] = 0;

   for(v=0;v<n;v++)
     if (visited[v] == 0) 
        DFS(v, graph, n, visited);

   printf("\n");  

}  

void read_matrix(int graph [][MAX], int n) {

    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
      for (j=0;j<n;j++)
          graph[i][j] = 0; 


   printf("\Input elements in format [ij], CTRL+D to end\n");

   while(scanf("%d%d", &i, &j) != EOF) {
      graph[i][j] = 1;  
   }

}
```

Comment: Scanf of 57 using %d%d will not give you 5,7

Comment: Yup, you're right. It seems what I gave as input was the problem.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> Input elements in format [ij]
> ```

Scanf of 57 using %d%d will not give you 5,7 – stark